# python my value of j change when for s in range(i,j-1): j=3 but before range it was j=2 ...please help me

Tags: python

```
for l in range(1,len(S)-1):
    for i in range(1,len(S)-l):
        j=i+l
        for X in N:
            max_score = 0
            args = None
            if j==2:
                print j
            for s in range(i,j-1):#s is for split point
                if j==2:
                    print j
                for W in probBiNonterDic.keys():#y<==>  X->YZ
                    if j==2:
                        print j
```

as you see that in first for block of X if j==2: print 2 but when in second block of s and W, if j==2 does not print 2...why is it, changing j value

Comment: Just an aside - using `l` (lower case `L`) as a variable name in a lot of fonts looks so similar to the number `1` it's often misleading... (but that's not what your issue is!)

Comment: If `j == 2` and you try to loop `for num in xrange(1, 2 - 1)` <-- this loop won't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both the l and i loop start a 1 and j = i + l. At this point j == 2 and prints out. When you try and loop from 1 to 1 in the s loop you actually don't loop even a single iteration and by the next time you get to the s loop j no longer equals 2.

```
>>> for x in xrange(1,1):
...     if True:
...         print "hi"
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is with the second `for` loop. You are trying to loop over a range that goes from `i --> j -1`, but because you increase the value of `j` at the beginning, this is the same as writing `range(i, i)`. Perhaps you could increment `j` at the bottom of the `for i in range(1, len(s) - 1)` loop.